# Radio button in react js using map

Tags: reactjs

I am creating quiz app where json data format is like the below one

```
    const data = [
        {
          id: 1,
          question_title: "Question1",
          Question_answer: [
            {
              answer_option: "option1",
              is_correct: false,
            },
            {
              answer_option: "option2",
              is_correct: false,
            },
            {
              answer_option: "option3",
              is_correct: false,
            },
            {
              answer_option: "option4",
              is_correct: true,
            },
          ],
        }
    ];
```

I have assigned `currentState` as 0, and my code is like this

```
    <h3>{data[currentQuestion].question_title}</h3>
    {data[currentQuestion].Question_answer.map((answer, key) => (
                <>
                  <label>
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      value={answer.answer_option}
                      name={answer.answer_option}
                      onClick={() => checkAnswer(answer)}
                    />
                    &nbsp;
                    {answer.answer_option}
                  </label>
                </>
              ))}
```

I want to select only one option at a time, but here its allowing me to select multiple option at a time, how can i select only one radio button at a time?

Comment: Please show detail about `checkAnswer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to give each input a `name` attribute, as that's what groups them together.

make sure the name you give doesn't repeat, otherwise you'll have multiple radio groups controlling the same value.

for more read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)

"A radio group is defined by giving each of radio buttons in the group the same name. Once a radio group is established, selecting any radio button in that group automatically deselects any currently-selected radio button in the same group"

```html
<input
type="radio"
name = {key}
value = { answer.answer_option }
name = { answer.answer_option }
onClick = {() => checkAnswer(answer)}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

There has to be a way for the parser to know that `input radios` are linked. `name` is the property. Ensure you are giving the same [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#defining_a_radio_group) to all of the inputs so you can select only one at a time.

From the docs:

> A radio group is defined by giving each of radio buttons in the group the same name. Once a radio group is established, selecting any radio button in that group automatically deselects any currently-selected radio button in the same group.

Here is an example using "question" as the name, you can choose any logical value.

```
                 <label>
                    <input
                      type="radio"
                      value={answer.answer_option}
                      name="question"
                      onClick={() => checkAnswer(answer)}
                    />
                    &nbsp;
                    {answer.answer_option}
                  </label>
```

Comment: @Thushar Shahi, this works , but the json data continues with id : 2 and id : 3 so on.... if i select 1st radio button in question 1, same radio button is checked in question 2, how to clear that